# Contributions to the nucleon-nucleon interaction potential in the deuteron

Tags: nuclear-physics

I've recently worked on obtaining the S-wave and D-wave functions of the deuteron and determine its magnetic dipole moment and electric quadrupole moment. I've considered a one-pion exchange potential between the nucleons only. Of course, I found slight deviations from the experimental values which I've read are due to other contributions to the potential that were not considered.
Which other contributions are there, i.e, which other nucleon-nucleon interaction potentials are there to be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-pion exchange, etc. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/9901012).

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 18 terms in the nucleon-nucleon potential, as show in the figure:

[image]

The original abstract that generated the commemorative license plate states:

*"We present a new high-quality nucleon-nucleon potential with explicit charge dependence and charge asymmetry, which we designate Argonne
v
18
. The model has a charge-independent part with 14 operator components that is an updated version of the Argonne
v
14
potential. Three additional charge-dependent and one charge-asymmetric operators are added, along with a complete electromagnetic interaction. The potential has been fit directly to the Nijmegen pp and np scattering database, low-energy nn scattering parameters, and deuteron binding energy. With 40 adjustable parameters it gives a
χ
2
per datum of 1.09 for 4301 pp and np data in the range 0–350 MeV."*

See:

Accurate nucleon-nucleon potential with charge-independence breaking

R. B. Wiringa, V. G. J. Stoks, and R. Schiavilla
Phys. Rev. C 51, 38 – Published 1 January 1995

Comment: So, who’s license plates that?

Comment: @JonCuster https://www.phy.anl.gov/theory/research/av18/